# Module settings error

Tags: 2sxc

DNN 8.0.4 | 2SXC 8.6

Whenever I try to go to the gear module settings for a 2SXC module, it throws an error: Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: 'ToSic.SexyContent.Settings' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the module definition not having successfully updated during upgrade from a prior version of 2SXC to the newer (in this case 2SXC 8.6) version.

To correct this you need to remove the following two entries from HOST > EXTENSIONS > 2sexy Content > Module Definitions:

settings    2sxc Content Settings   DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/Settings.ascx

*- AND -*

settingswrapper 2sxc Content Settings   DesktopModules/ToSIC_SexyContent/SettingsWrapper.ascx